# Android - Dim app screen on longpress listitem

Tags: android, android-layout, background, dialog, long-press

I have an app with a listview. If you long press an item in the listview, you will get a DragShadow. Now if you got the dragshadow for drag&drop actions, I want to dim my appscreen like the way it is done in a dialog.

So is it possible to get a dim on your appscreen without using a dialog?

[image: I want to achieve this background dim/blur without using a dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alpha animation on your parent layout of taht screen on long press, with the help of this you can make your screen dim without dialog

```
  Animation animation2 = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.2f);
  animation2.setDuration(1000);
  animation2.setStartOffset(5000);
  layout.startAnimation(animation2);
```

or use animation through xml file

[XML Animations](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/)

Comment: Hi Vaibhav thanks for the comment, but the problem is I use an actionbar and that doesn't fade with this solution like the alertdialog